# One query for two similar tables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

i have two similar tables with the same fields. One is named "input" and the other "product" Both have the same fields:

- id
- name
- qty
- unit
- price
- pic(fk - both reference the same picture table).

My first question is: How can I write a query to effectively return every item's details?

I use JSON to export this data

```
$json_data.='"rec'.$i.'":{"id":"'.$id.'", "name":"'.$name.'", "price":"'.$price.'", "qty":"'.$qty.'", "units":"'.$unit.'", "pic":"'.$pic.'"},';`.
```

My second question is: How can i effectively reference all the fields from both tables?

NB: I don't want to put the two categories in the same table, say, `item`, with an additional field of `category`.

Just to rectify this: the join condition is (input.pic=pic.id and product.pic=pic.id)

Comment: Use a simple JOIN to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you have two tables with the same fields?

Comment: there is a possibility of their structures changing later, by adding different fields to either. that's my reason for keeping them differently.

Answer (score 1):

If the tables have the same fields you can do a union query.

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM table2
```

if they are similar as you say then you just have to select the fields that they have in common into both

```
 SELECT "table1" as source_table,id,name,qty,unit,price from table1
 UNION
 select "table2" as source_table,id,name,qty,unit,price from table2
```

note I added a source table so you could backtrack where you got it from .... cheers

Answer (score 0):

use full outer in mysql this is not possible so use/take help of union to get all the rows

```
SELECT * FROM input
LEFT JOIN product ON input.id = product.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM input
    RIGHT JOIN product ON input.id = product.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that scenario is the word "efficient". The pic - input - `leftjoin` is slower than an inner join, and the sum of `left join input` and `left join output` is slower than a simple `inner join`.

```
select pic.id as pic_id, pic.data, input.id as input_id, output.id as output_id, input....
from pic 
left join input on input.pic_id = pic.id
left join output on output.pic_id = pic.id
```

or

```
select pic.id as pic_id, pic.data, "input" as type, input.id as id, input....
from pic 
inner join input on input.pic_id = pic.id
union
select pic.id as pic_id, pic.data, "output" as type, output.id as id, output....
from pic 
inner join output on output.pic_id = pic.id
```

The union is faster, because of using two inner joins.